# using attr_accessor for validation always returns an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to validate 2 fields which do no belong to the `User` table

```
attr_accessor :terms_of_service, :privacy_policy

 validates :terms_of_service, presence: true
 validates :privacy_policy, presence: true
```

in the request sent from the client, the `:terms_of_service` and `:privacy_policy` arguments can either be absent, or a boolean value.

Rails needs to pass validation only if the value is `true` (i.e send error only if parameter is absent or false)

however , for some reason - validation always fails regardless of the parameters being true or absent/false

I've even tried

```
 validates_presence_of :terms_of_service
 validates_presence_of :privacy_policy
```

and also

```
  validates :terms_of_service, acceptance: true
  validates :privacy_policy, acceptance: true
```

these are the params i'm sending to rails

```
{"username"=>"justin", "email"=>"justin@justin.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "terms_of_service"=>false, "privacy_policy"=>false, "confirm_success_url"=>"http://localhost:4000", "config_name"=>"default", "registration"=>{"username"=>"justin", "email"=>"justin@justin.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "terms_of_service"=>false, "privacy_policy"=>false, "confirm_success_url"=>"http://localhost:4000"}}
```

when i try to log the below using

```
puts "terms_of_service : #{:terms_of_service}"
```

i get the below output

```
terms_of_service : terms_of_service
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that i did not properly sanitize my params

this is what i did in my `applicationController.rb`

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?


def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username,:terms_of_service,:privacy_policy])
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a custom validator. `presence: true` checks for the existence of the field so it would pass if its set to anything including false.

```
validate :privacy_policy_valid?

privacy
def privacy_policy?
  errors.add(:privacy_policy "must be true") if privacy_policy
end
```

For your logging statement try

```
puts "terms_of_service : #{terms_of_service}"
```